# Getting current Item in a databound item

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am adding a few push ping to a map that is bounded to a datasource.

```
        <my:Map Height="340" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,100,0,0" Name="settingsmap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="438" CredentialsProvider="_">
            <my:MapItemsControl Name="settingsMapItemControl" MouseLeftButtonDown="settingsMapItemControl_MouseLeftButtonDown">
                <my:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <my:Pushpin Location="{Binding location}">
                        </my:Pushpin>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </my:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </my:MapItemsControl>
        </my:Map>
```

The push pin binds to "location"  member of dataitem.

Now when someone clicks the pin (or touches in phone ) how can I get the item that was bound to the pin (from the list of objects bound to map) ?
I want to basically get the item so that I can display other information like name etc at bottom of screen. Or say something like you have selected "xyz"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using MVVM, put an EventTrigger and an InvokeCommandAction on the Pushpin, and bind the DataContext itself to the Command parameter.

```
<my:Pushpin Location="{Binding location}">
 <i:Interactivity.Triggers>
   <i:EventTrigger EventName="Tap">
     <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding PushpinClick}" 
         CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
   <i:Interactivity.Triggers>
</my:Pushpin>
```

And simply have an ICommand named PusphinClick in your VM, and you'll get the data in the parameter of `Execute`

If you're NOT using MVVM then it'll get a little trickier - try attaching a MouseLeftButtonDown eventhandler to the pushpin. In the event handler, you can get the "Data" by getting `(sender as Pushpin).DataContext` as YourDataItem...

Comment: (sender as Pushpin).DataContext => null

Comment: is the DataContext null or is the sender not a Pushpin?

Comment: cause if the Pushpin wouldn't have a DataContext, then `{Binding location}` shouldn't work either (unless you're doing something from codebehind and not telling us...